# Function evaluation from area

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Can we find a smooth continuous $  f(z)$ if

$$ \int_1^3 f(x) dx = \dfrac{26}{3},\; \int_2^4 f(y) dy=\dfrac{56}{3} ?$$

EDIT1:

What I actually wanted to ask was:

[image]

If $( f,g )$ are functions inverse of each other then find $f(x)$

$$ \int_1^3 f(x) dx + \int_2^4 g(y) dy=10 $$

Answer is known as *any function* as being "obvious" but how to go about showing the same?

Comments appreciated.

Comment: Surely not; you could cook up both a 'rectangular' step function and a 'triangular' one with these definite integrals.

Comment: I meant smooth continuous functions.

Comment: If your questions is, 'can we find such an $f$?', the answer is clearly yes; $f(x)=x^2$ works. If your question is, 'do these definite integrals uniquely determine $f(x)$?', the answer is clearly no. One could simply add any function whose definite integral on $[1,3]$ and $[2,4]$ is zero, for instance $\sin(200\pi x)$; for a less obvious counterexample, try $f(x) = \frac{28561 \log \left({28/13}\right)}{25830}(28/13)^x$.

Comment: @Narasimham some guessing involved : as $$\int_1^3f(x+1)-f(x)=56/3-26/3=10$$ and $$\int_1^3 2x+1=10$$ we guess $$f(x+1)-f(x)=2x+1$$ solving the recursion $f(x)=x^2$ is definitely one solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take *any two* smooth functions and form the linear combination $af(x)+bg(x)$.

Now solve the linear system

$$a\int_1^3f\,dx+b\int_1^3g\,dx=\frac{26}3,\\a\int_2^4f\,dx+b\int_2^4g\,dx=\frac{56}3.$$

I fail to see where the difficulty lies.

---

You can even start from antiderivatives and solve

$$a(F(3)-F(1))+b(G(3)-G(1))=\frac{26}3,\\a(F(4)-F(2))+b(G(4)-G(2))=\frac{56}3.$$

Comment: There's a certain matrix that needs to be invertible.

Comment: @J.G.: yes, for sure.

Comment: Thanks, actually meant to query with inverse functions, somehow ended with a  botched up question, shall close for now.

Answer (score 1):

The $26$ is a dead give-a-way.  It's $3^3-1^3$.  The $3$ in the denominator clinches it: $f(x) = x^2$.  Then just check the other integral.

Comment: Did so on purpose, looking a method ( outside  a guess) if there is..

Answer (score 1):

No constant $f$ will do, but the next simplest option is linear. Say $f(x)=ax+b$ so$$4a+2b=\frac{26}{3},\,6a+2b=\frac{56}{3}\iff a=5,\,b=-\frac{17}{3}.$$

Comment: +1 as a lenear function well hidden was found ,(you could also add that this could be extended  for higher degree polynomials except that more undetermined coeffcients pop up)

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore: the trick is to find two linearly independent functions, of any kind.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore: in the context of the question.

Answer (score 0):

We can find a lot of functions with this property.

Consider $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3$ or any other polynomial. It's easy to notice that we have
$$ \int_1^3 f(x) dx = \dfrac{26}{3},\; \int_2^4 f(y) dy=\dfrac{56}{3} $$
for many $f(x)$ of such type.